# Finding row Indexes based on ID Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy specific row based on ID, but for now i'm strugling and getting only 1 row copied to another sheet, what i need to do is when i select ID to copy all the rows with the same ID into another sheet

```
let array= [];
const catchID= (searchID) => {  
  for(let i=0; i < rangeID.length; i++) {
    if(rangeID[i][0] === trazeniID){
      array.push(rangeID[i]);
    }
  }
  return array;
}
catchID(searchID);

const copyToAnotherSheet= () => {
  
  const selectedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const selectedCellRowIndex = selectedCell.getRow(); // get selected row 

  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(selectedCellRowIndex,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  

  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Another Sheet');
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1);

  for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == searchID) {
      if(statusCell.getValue() === 'Payed' || statusCell.getValue() === 'Reinvest') {
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
        
      }
    }else{
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Something went wrong')
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
picture bellow shows for example: based on ID A277 should get copied all
rows to another sheet which depends on the row index. I hope i explained my situation well.

Comment: This example is incomplete and not reproducible.  Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the columns "B" and "L" are "A277" and "Payed" or "Reinvest", you want to copy the rows from the source sheet to the destination sheet using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `sheet`, `searchID` and `statusCell` are not declared.
- Unfortunately, I cannot understand `rangeID`. So I couldn't understand `array`.

  - From your script, I thought that `array` might be the values from the source sheet.

When these points are reflected in a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const copyToAnotherSheet = () => {
  const searchID = "A277"; // Please set the search text.
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const [,...srcValues] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const copyValues = srcValues.filter(r => r[1] == searchID && (r[11] == 'Payed' || r[11] == 'Reinvest'));
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, copyValues.length, copyValues[0].length).setValues(copyValues);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Yeah, i am  sorry for bad reproducible example but this is basically what i need!
Thank a lot!

Comment: @Aleksa Veselinovic Thank you for your response.